# How to convert format with DateTime createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime, date-format

i have probleme with DateTime::createFromFormat. I want create with specific format : `Y-d-m`

i try this

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-d-m H:i:s", $myFirstDate->format('Y-d-m H:i:s'));
```

The result is (for var_dump($date)) :

```
object(DateTime)#400 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-04-16 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
```

This is wrong format `(Y-m-d)`
`$myFirstDate` is a datetime object with `Y-m-d` format and I want to inverse day and month
the `var_dump($myFirstDate)` is the same like `$date`

Thank you

Julien

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you saying that the format in the `var_dump` output is wrong? That's not how it works. `DateTime` objects don't have an internal "format" - once it's an object, debugging it will always show it as **Y-m-d H:i:s.u** format.

Comment: Oh :s because i want Y-d-m H:i:s format in, it is possible ?

Comment: `$myFirstDate is a datetime object with Y-m-d format`

No! `$myFirstDate` is simply a datetime object.... it doesn't have any format until you tell it what format to use.

Comment: Do you just want the output of `$myFirstDate->format('Y-d-m H:i:s')`? As it is, you're just creating an identical copy of an object you already have.

Comment: I dont need string return, i want the real object datetime with specific format to use with doctrine and sql server.

Comment: *real object datetime with specific format* doesn't make sense. Like I say, the objects themselves don't have a format - it's only when you call `format()` (or debug them with var_export, etc) that any formatting happens. Doctrine specifically should deal just fine with DateTime objects, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thx for answers

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime Object holds the date and time in a standard format i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss`. It of course has to hold it in a standard/sensible format so you can easily mess with the formats using the `->format()` method.

If you want to display it in another format just use the `->format()` method to either display it or place the result in a text variable for later use

```
echo $myFirstDate->format('Y-d-m H:i:s');
```

or

```
$display_date = $myFirstDate->format('Y-d-m H:i:s');
```

Comment: Doctrine will expect a date format in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss format if you are using a DateTime defined column in a table. If you are not using a DateTime defined format on your database then you should be for that same reasons that the PHP DateTime object does